# Xamarin Forms / Android ScrollView with Paging, same as UIScrollView.PagingEnabled

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to create a scroll view with pages that can be scrolled vertically and horizontally as well. 
The scroller should be just like a slideshow on a website, to slide between images (content). Something like ScrollView, but to stop at a certain point when scrolled.

I am using this in Xamarin.Forms, so I'll need to create a custom renderer (Android) and set the content of the pages from Forms.

I tried ViewPagers, but I want to be able to set the content from Forms page, not from predefined layouts...

I just couldn't find a clear example/tutorial so I can understand how to approach this problem. I also think about overriding some methods from ScrollViewRenderer class, to intercept and only slide to a certain point, but have no idea which methods and properties to change.

Something like CarouselPage on XF, which can be used inside a layout.

Any help or examples would really be appreciated. Thanks!
I'm searching for 2 days for a solution for this problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution to it?...